# Using Linux Cron to Run Task every Fortnight

Tags: linux, cron, jobs

I have a server running Linux operating system. I am trying to schedule a cron job to run a task every two weeks (Fortnight) in Tuesday at 9am. 
I can only manage to run the task manually by comment (if I don’t want to run the job for this week) and uncomment (if I want to run the job for this week) as following:

```
0 9 * * 2   root    java -jar test.jar   // will run

# 0 9 * * 2 root    java -jar test.jar   // will not run
```

I have attempted to use the following cron job:

```
0 9 * * 2  case $(($(date +\%s) / (60*60*24*7))) in *[02468]) root  java -jar test.jar
```

But this cron script does not seem to work.

Any thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to execute at 4AM every one of two tuesdays :

```
0 4 * * 2 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 1 && execute_cmd
```

We first get week number with `date` and correct formatting, then the 'one time out of two' thing is done by using 'test' command.

'test' evaluates to true or false depending on a given expression, here, it evaluates whether $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) equals 1 (hence -eq 1), in other words it returns true if the week number is odd.

So this crontab will execute on odd weeks, on tuesday (2) at 4 AM (0 4).

More in-depth details here : 
https://serverfault.com/questions/633264/cronjob-run-every-two-weeks-on-saturday-starting-on-this-saturday

Comment: What does test mean, I guess the user name? I can't find any clues about "test" in the reference you have given? @sco

Comment: So for the command I want to run, using your solution, it is going to be like this 0 9 * * 2 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && root java -jar test.jar, assuming the first run start from this week. Is that right?

Comment: 'test' starts at the 11th character of the example of the accepted answer of the reference I gave. More info on test here : http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html. 'test' is a command, it evaluates to true or false a given expression, here, it evaluates whether $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) equals 1 (hence -eq 1), in other words it returns true if the week number is odd. Your proposal looks good to me indeed, we are week 24, it shall trigger tomorrow morning (depending on your actual timezone of course).

Comment: Excellent SCO, great help. I will give it to go and see if this will run as expected tomorrow.

Comment: I ran this script today 30 12    * * 2   root    test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 0 && ( java -jar /emailReminders/emailReminder.jar ). Unfortunately, the script does not run. In the mail log file, it shows this message "/bin/sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "10#23%2"". I am surprising why it considers this week as 23, this week is expected to be 24? Also, I make sure I add an empty line as the last line in the file in the crontab file. I run

Comment: @IbrahimEL-Sanosi, sorry, my bad, we are week 23. Maybe your default Cron shell dsoesn't support for base setting. Did you tried with SHELL=/bin/bash as the first line of your crontab to force for Bash shell ?

Comment: I use %V instead of %W. %V results in 24 which is correct. Yes, when I use SHELL=/bin/bash, it works! Thank you